# x? quantifer: Why does a non-x give a "zero-length" match?

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

A quantifier `x?` means `a single or no occurance of x`.

I am posting a `test harness` for matching the regex with strings for convenience.

**I am confused about the regex `a?` when compared to the string `ababaaaab`.**

The **output** of the program is:

```
Enter your regex: a?

Enter your input string to seacrh: ababaaaab

I found the text "a" starting at index 0 and ending at index 1.
I found the text "" starting at index 1 and ending at index 1. 
I found the text "a" starting at index 2 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "" starting at index 3 and ending at index 3.
I found the text "a" starting at index 4 and ending at index 5.
I found the text "a" starting at index 5 and ending at index 6.
I found the text "a" starting at index 6 and ending at index 7.
I found the text "a" starting at index 7 and ending at index 8.
I found the text "" starting at index 8 and ending at index 8.
I found the text "" starting at index 9 and ending at index 9.

Enter your regex:
```

**I am confused about the b's.**

> "The regular expression a? is not specifically looking for the letter
>   "b"; it's merely looking for the presence (or lack thereof) of the
>   letter "a". If the quantifier allows for a match of "a" zero times,
>   anything in the input string that's not an "a" will show up as a
>   zero-length match."

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)

**QUESTION:-**

The first line is understandable, and I do understand that presence of b or any non-a is an absence of a, or 0 occurence of a, so should result in a match. **But the absence of a (that is the occurance of b) is between the indices 1 and 2. So why is the match of the text "" between the index 1 and 1 (in other words, why are we getting a zero-length match here).** From my reasoning, it should be between the indices 1 and 2.

---

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/*
 *  Enter your regex: foo
 *  Enter input string to search: foo
 *  I found the text foo starting at index 0 and ending at index 3.
 * */

public class RegexTestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        /*Console console = System.console();
        if (console == null) {
            System.err.println("No console.");
            System.exit(1);
        }*/

        while (true) {

            /*Pattern pattern = 
            Pattern.compile(console.readLine("%nEnter your regex: ", null));*/

            System.out.print("\nEnter your regex: ");

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(scanner.next());

            System.out.print("\nEnter your input string to seacrh: ");

            Matcher matcher = 
            pattern.matcher(scanner.next());

            boolean found = false;
            while (matcher.find()) {
                /*console.format("I found the text" +
                    " \"%s\" starting at " +
                    "index %d and ending at index %d.%n",
                    matcher.group(),
                    matcher.start(),
                    matcher.end());*/

                System.out.println("I found the text \"" + matcher.group() + "\" starting at index " + matcher.start() + " and ending at index " + matcher.end() + "."); 

                found = true;
            }
            if(!found){
                //console.format("No match found.%n", null);
                System.out.println("No match found."); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the absence of a (that is the occurance of b) is between the indices 1 and 2. So why is the match of the text "" between the index 1 and 1 (in other words, why are we getting a zero-length match here)

The length of the match is the length of the input string that matched the pattern.

Since there was no "a", only an empty string was matched.

Again, the pattern does not match "a sequence of non-a characters", it matches a (possibly empty) sequence of "a"s up to a total length of one. In this case, that matched sequence was empty.

> But the absence of a (that is the occurance of b)

The absence of a is **not** the occurance of b. The absence of a takes place *before* the occurance of b and ends at the occurance of b.

Comment: To `b` or not to `b`... Great answer.

Comment: Also, compare this to the pattern `[^a]` which does match a "non-a".

Comment: @Mena 2 b || ¬ 2 b ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**The position reported is not the position of a character**

The key thing to understand is that the regex engine is not giving you the position of a character where it found a match.

It is giving you the starting position where it started the match that was successful. That position is not a character. It is the space between characters. For instance,

- Position 0 is the very beginning of the string. That is where the `\A` or `^` assertions match.
- Position 1 is the position between the first and the second characters.
- Position 9 is the position after the last `b` at the end of `ababaaaab`. That is where the `\Z` or `$` assertions match.

Comment: ...and 9 is after the last character, and where `$` matches.

Answer (score 0):

`a?` is greedy. In other words, the regex engine will process as follow:

```
foreach index
    if next char is "a"
        return "a"
    else if next char is ""
        return ""
    end if
end foreach
```

If you apply this algorithm on your input string, you'll have the same output as the one you provided.

---

You could try its non-greedy (or lazy) equivalent: `a??`. The regex engine would then process as follow:

```
foreach index
    if next char is ""
        return ""
    else if next char is "a"
        return "a"
    end if
end foreach
```

An empty string would thus be found at each index, and no `a` would be outputted at all.