# How to understand the way the expression \d{0} evaluate a number?

Tags: regex

Hi I just start learning on regex and got a question right away.
I was playing around the expression and replacing the digits in a number "516.52" with a X.

So I tried the follows without a problem

`\d{1}` result: XXX.XX

`\d{2}` result: X6.X

`\d{3}` result: X.52

But why is this case?

`\d{0}` result: X5X1X6X.X5X2X

My original is that each digit in a number is evalued by the expression, and extend the digit when the expression has a quantifier. However, in the case of `\d{0}` , it seems that it would evaluate "the nothings" between/ before/ after the digits as well. May I ask how to understand the way the computer take regex expression and evaluate the data?

Comment: `\d{0}` will match between any characters (zero length), [same like `.{0}`](https://regex101.com/r/kcFrKn/1) - it does not make much sense though.

Comment: Well `\d{0}` matches 0 repetitions of a digit, which is indeed nothing, and that can be found everywhere.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369618/why-do-regex-engines-allow-automatically-attempt-matching-at-the-end-of-the-in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24239573/x-quantifer-why-does-a-non-x-give-a-zero-length-match

Comment: That indeed an interesting behaviour. So is it correct to said that: With an expression, the machine would evaluate each character and the null value between each of two characters?